# Does a function have multiple Big-$O$'s?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, definition

[The Wikipedia page for Big-$O$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) states that we write $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ iff
$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|}<\infty.$$
But does this not imply that $f$ is $O$ of multiple functions? For instance, $f(x)=2x^3+x$ is $O(x^3)$ since $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{2x^3+x}{x^3}\right|}=2<\infty$. But we must also have that $f$ is $O(e^x)$, since $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{2x^3+x}{e^x}\right|}=0<\infty$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Certainly. Any function is big-O of many other functions.

Comment: You aren't missing anything: this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

More over it holds $$f \in O(g), g \in O(h) \Rightarrow f\in O(h)$$

As you can see I prefer to write $f \in O(g)$ instead of $f = O(g)$ to make it clear that $f$ is only one of many functions which is in $O(g)$

Comment: Is there then a term for the "slowest-growing big $O$"? That is, the big $O$ that is typically expressed for a function, for instance, $O(x^5)$ for $2x^5+3x^2$?

Comment: Slowest growing.  Sumetimes written as $\Theta$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann–Landau_notations

Answer (score 0):

Yes for course, and it is also true for the little-o as for example

$$\sin x-x=o(x)$$

but also

$$\sin x-x=o(1), \quad \sin x-x=o(x^2)$$

and in general

$$\sin x-x=o(x^\alpha)$$

with $\alpha\in(-\infty,3)$.